# Cyclotomic polynomial dividing $f\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

I know that $\varphi (n)\geq \sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$ for natural numbers $n$, and that the cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. Let $f\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$ be a polynomial of degree $m$ with root $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$, where $\alpha ^k=1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}\backslash \{ 0\}$. I must show that there is an $l\leq 2m^2$ s.t. $\Phi_l\mid f$.

I understand that if $\Phi_l\mid f$ then $l\leq 2m^2$, but I can't show that $\Phi_l\mid f$. Do you have any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much got all the right ingredients -- all you need to do is put them together in the right order.

Since $\mathbb Q[X]$ is a unique factorization domain (well, all we need is that it's a GCD domain), we can find $\gcd(f,\Phi_\ell)$ for various $\ell$. Since $\Phi_\ell$ is irreducible, this is either $\Phi_\ell$ or a constant: what happens if it's a constant for all $\ell$?

Comment: This constant must be 1 to divide $\Phi _l$ for all $l$, right?

Comment: @infiniteMonkeyCage Depends how you define the gcd -- most definitions (over $\mathbb Q[X]$) will take it to be monic, in which case any constant is $1$ by the definition of gcd. Since the units of $\mathbb Q[X]$ are just $\mathbb Q$, the value of the constant is doesn't matter so much.

Comment: Ah, right, I see

Comment: Is $X-\alpha$ a factor in $\Phi _l$?

Comment: I'm really having trouble concluding

Comment: @infiniteMonkeyCage If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ share a root, then can $\gcd(f(x),g(x))$ be a constant? Remember that it can be written as $f(x)r(x)+g(x)s(x)$ for some polynomials $r$ and $s$.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now.